# Adding numbers in defined set and printing it in Python

Tags: python, arrays, set

I am trying to input the 5 numbers in defined length set and try to print out those numbers but it's giving "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" this error.

```
print("enter 5 numbers")
a=set(5)
for i in range(0,5):
    a.append(int(input("enter a number")))
for i in range(0,5):
    print("numbers in array are",a[i])
```

Comment: sets are not arrays! Your code would fail because 5 is not iterable. Also set has add and not append to add elements. Getting element by index from set will also not work.

Comment: also, `set` does not have a method `.append()`; maybe you want to use `.add()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix the size of set while creating.

`a = set(5)` is the source of your error.

Also, sets do not have `append` method. You should use `a.add("data")` for adding elements to the set.

To ensure that the size of set does not exceed a particular length, you can try something like this

```
fixed_length = 3
a=set()
for i in range(0,5):
    if len(a) == fixed_length:
        break
    else:
        a.add(int(input("enter a number")))

for index, element in enumerate(a):
    print("numbers in array are", element)
```

Comment: So how can I store 5 numbers given by a user and then print them?

Comment: @AaquibAhmedDiaz I have updated the answer to include the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion on what `set` actually does. I assume you want to make a predefined set of length 5. When doing:

```
set(5)
```

you get:

```
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

because you're trying to make a set containing only the integer 5. If you want to make a `set` from that, you would have to include an iterable, maybe like so:

```
set((5,))

Out: {5}
```

But what I would recommend you to do is declare

```
a = []  # create an empty list
```

and then run your code. At the end then, I would make a `set` by typing

```
a = set(a)
```

Hopefully that was helpful for you! Have fun coding! :)

Comment: `{5}` instead of `set((5,))`

Comment: it is shorter, yes. but i was trying to highlight the difference to the code before here